# How to hyperlink to a location in a dynamic cell in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a dynamic cell, with a file path written in it. The file path changes automatically based on another selection. 
How do I make it that so, when you click that cell, it automatically opens whatever file path is written in it?

Ex : if cell `A1` contains "**C:\Documents\example.txt**", then clicking on the cell should open the file "**example.txt**"
If cell `A1` was changed to "**C:\Documents\example2.txt**", then clicking on the cell should open the file "**example2.txt**".

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on that cell and choosing Hyperlink followed by locating that text file in your computer ?

Comment: The hyperlink is dynamic. I want the hyperlink to open the location written in the cell, and as that location changes, the hyperlink changes too to that new location.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We need more details about what you are doing. You need to explain better what you are doing because there aren't enough details about how you are using a list, how the hyperlinks are created (imbedded or using the HYPERLINK function) and how the cells are changed. How did you create the list and how is it used? The more details the better. Otherwise, you will get a bunch of vague answers.

Comment: I've been lurking for years, no need for the welcome lol

Comment: I've tried `=HYPERLINK(A1,"click here")` but that produces a simple hyperlink to cell "A1"
`=HYPERLINK(**formula**,"click here")` still doesn't work!

Answer (score 3):

Include your dynamic referance in the HYPERLINK function for example:

```
=HYPERLINK(E1)
```

or

```
=HYPERLINK(E1,"Click Here")
```

You can use any advanced formula instead of E1.

Comment: Well, that actually would be a hyperlink to cell E1, and not to the file which I want!

Comment: Also, adding a formula instead of "E1", does not produce a clickable hyperlink.

Comment: In cell A1 I have the path to my file (c:\temp\test.txt) and in cell B1, I have the formula =HYPERLINK(A1) and in B1 I get a clickable link to the file.

Comment: @dimblefeck I tried that before, doesn't work!
The path to my file has underscores, and the hyperlink function just converts them to spaces!

Comment: If you provide us more details we may be able to further help you. If your formula doesn't work, show us that formula.

Comment: That formula was the one you posted in your answer, I tried it before you posted that, and it didn't work!

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010 and have tested a file with underscores in it and it is fine for me. A curios difference between me and thee. I've tried it with files local to my PC and on a server using both the mapped drive letter and UNC path, all OK.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013, could be a bug that's converting my underscores to spaces, or could be that the hyperlink function itself doesn't support spaces and so uses underscores instead.

Comment: Instead of E1 you need to referance the cell that its value is a location of a file on your computer as you described in your question. If this would be A1 it would open that location. If however the value of A1 is not something you can link to, it will simply link to cell A1.

Comment: I already did that, doesn't work.
If the file path is in cell A1, then making
`=HYPERLINK(A1)` in cell B1, doesn't work.

Comment: Try with locations that its path doesn't include spaces. If you have a problem with underscores, try a location that doesn't include underscores as well.

Comment: If the file path has spaces, it works fine. 
If the file path has underscores, the hyperlink function makes them spaces!
If the file path has no spaces or underscores at all, it works fine.

Comment: nvm, I just fixed it.

Comment: @ExcelGuy I'd be interested in how you fixed that.

Comment: Well, I half-fixed it, I haven't yet completed the entire spreadsheet to be able to test that everything is working properly.

Comment: Was this a satisfied answer? If yes, please mark as accepted. Otherwise, please edit your question to describe what’s not working.

Answer (score 0):

Click on a cell you want to hyperlink and **CTRL+K** to bring up the "Insert Hyperlink" window.  Type in the URL and click OK.  Or, you can browse for the file on your computer as well and it will use the standard Windows path (C:\Users\You\Desktop\file.txt).

You can Cut/Paste this cell and the Hyperlink will stay with it.

Comment: Um, this won't produce a _dynamic_ hyperlink, that changes based on the contents of the cell!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

=HYPERLINK("C:\Documents\" & A1 & ".txt","click here!")

Use A1 As your input cell and Place this formula into some other cell.  Just type the document name into A1 and the formula is dynamic in that way.

A drop down list might be useful to eliminate typo errors

More generally:

=HYPERLINK("[Location pathway]\" & A1 & ".[filetype]","Click Here!")